# How to deploy Kube-Controller-Master?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have installed Kubernetes with minikube, which is a single node cluster. 
There is a yaml file to deploy controller master but it showing

> Back-off restarting failed container Error syncing pod

Can someone solve this issue?

link for the yaml file is here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/blob/master/docs/admin/high-availability/kube-controller-manager.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubernetes controller manager is a core component of Kubernetes and already running in every Kubernetes cluster, usually in form of a standalone pod managed by the Kubernetes addon manager. Minikube uses `localkube` which [integrates the controller manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/pkg/localkube/controller-manager.go) together with other Kubernetes core components in a single binary to simplify setup of single-node clusters for testing purposes. If you want to change options of the integrated controller manager or other components, use the `--extra-config` option of `minikube start`.

The example you linked is a custom deployment of the controller manager used for highly available multi-master clusters. If you want to test this you need to set up your cluster manually, minikube is not the right tool for this.

Comment: Thanks !! but how can I use it ?

Comment: You are already using it, there is no interaction required. What do you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to change the --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period value. It contains 30 secs by default. I want it to be 10 secs. It can be updated only using kube controller master

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Comment: Look at the `--extra-config` option of `minikube start`. You can change options of Kubernetes componets with this flag during cluster creation.

Comment: Thanks simt !! 
I did it like this 
minikube start --extra-config kube-controller-master.horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period=10